# How do I used D3 to force a user click on a circle object inside of a g.node object?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have some pretty complex code that runs when a user selects a node in my D3 tree. I want to force a UI click programatically. I've tried several of the suggestions on stack overflow, but I think I have a special case.

```
//This is how I create the nodes...

    node = nodeElements.selectAll("g.node")
                .data(nodes, function(d) {return d.name;});   

    nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
                .attr("class", "node")
                .attr("name", function(d){return d.name;});

    nodeEnter.append("circle")
                .attr("r", 10)
                .attr("show", true)
                .attr("class", "displayNode")
                .on("click", mouseClickNode); //<---I want to trigger this
```

I think I should be selecting the circle under my node element.

I've tried a lot of things, here are a few

```
//Tried
    d3.select("g.node[name='someNodeName']>circle.displayNode").on("click")();
//Tried
    d3.select("g.node[name='someNodeName']>circle").on("click")();
//I got desperate...
    node.filter(function(d){
            if(d.name === "someNodeName"){
                return d;
            }   
        }).on("click")();
```

Comment: Does `d3.select("g.node[name='someNodeName']").selectAll("circle.displayNode").on("click")()` work?

Comment: In the UI I use a polygon to indicate what node is selected. It's a child in one of the g.node elements. I have a function that scans the dom, finds the 1 node with the polygon and returns the name of the node, that's where someNodeName comes from. The code for the polygon is solid. With:   d3.select("g.node[name='"+selectedNodeFound+"']").select("circle").on("click")();      I can register some sort of click because my polygon vanishes. However, I can't get the program to select the node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have problems selecting the right circle to trigger the event on? Or is it the triggering itself? The selector `g.node[name='someNodeName']>circle.displayNode` is looking good.

If your handler function uses the bound data, the `.on('click')();` is not the way you want to go. Instead build your own event to fire off:

```
d3.select('#btn').on('click', function() {
    var e = document.createEvent('UIEvents');
    e.initUIEvent('click', true, true);        
    d3.select('g.node[name="foo"]>circle.displayNode').node().dispatchEvent(e);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/risto/xby0qzmz/)

Comment: This worked. I just had to modify this line: e.initUIEvent('click', true, false, window, 1);   THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

I can't really try out your code but I believe I have done similar things. What I used was much simpler

```
d3.selectAll('.node')
.on("click",mouseClickNode);
```

What happens here that you have a selection for anything in the class node. When one of them is clicked your function mouseClickNode will run for that node only.

The difference is in me using selectAll. Using select will only select the first node.